# Can't seem to switch to another storyboard via a UIButton

Tags: ios11, xcode9, swift4

When I'm trying to switch from one view to another using Swift 4 on XCode 9, it gives me this error.

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

I'm using a button to switch from `Main` to `LandingView`. `Main` is the default view(main.storyboard) while `LandingView` is another view controller within `main.storyboard`.

Here's the code I'm using to get this to work.

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LandingView")
self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

*[Above] All contained in a IBAction for the button I want to use.*

Just to clarify, `LandingView` is a Storyboard ID that I'm using to make the switch from default view to LandingView. Please note this is all contained under `Main.storyboard`.

Comment: Post some more info of your crash log. Also make sure you're assigning unique `Identifier`s to each one of your screens if you're using Storyboard.

Comment: Used segues instead. Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified newViewController's type.

Try this:

```
    let storyBoard: UIStoryBoard = UIStoryBoard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LandingView") as! younewViewControllerType
    self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To determine what you have declared your LandingView ViewController Subclass, you can reference Identity Inspector in Interface builder as in the image below:

[image]

Under Custom Class, the Class property defines your custom subclass.  When declaring your newViewController, you must declare it as that type.

Comment: What would the type be?

Comment: It is probably LandingViewController.

Comment: Use of undeclared type 'UIStoryBoard' error. Are you sure this is Swift 4?

Comment: Have you set the type of newViewController?

Comment: ```
let storyBoard: UIStoryBoard = UIStoryBoard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LandingView") as! MainViewController
self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```
This is what it looks like now.

Comment: Why is the Destination ViewController cast as:
as! MainViewController

Comment: You are wasting my time and I'm down voting you.

Comment: Because the view I want to switch to uses that ViewController file and is it's custom class name. UIStoryBoard is incorrect, bud. I'm asking for help not misdirection.